# Color picker not adding to dynamic HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css, color-picker

Im trying to add a color picker to a HTML but its not working.

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/csgn6051/2/

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<button id="add">
  Add to table
</button>
</button>
<table id="points-table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>line-item</td>
    <td>color-picker</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#add').click(function() {
    alert('clicked')
    $('#points-table tr:last').after('<tr>' + '<td>1</td>'

      + '<td>   <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567"/>    </td></tr>');

  })


})
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen exactly?

Comment: Your script is only adding a row to your table with a hard-coded value to it. I'm not sure what about this makes you expect a color-picker to show up.

Comment: I edited the fiddle and added the new version..Im expecting the colorpicker to be displayed on the HTML table as well.

Comment: The plugin check for class only on DOMContentLoaded. To initialize new element, you need to call it explecitely: http://jscolor.com/examples/#example-instantiating  See e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/csgn6051/3/

Comment: Thanks much..I did not notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the color value using `.val()` and assign it to a variable. Then use the variable fir the input value in the table.

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/csgn6051/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add').click(function() {
    var color = $('#color').val();
    $('#points-table tr:last').after('<tr>' + '<td>1</td>'
      + '<td>   <input class="jscolor" value="'+color+'"/>    </td></tr>');

   //This part below came from the comment by A. Wolf
   new jscolor($('#points-table tr:last').find('.jscolor')[0])
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can get the color value in this way: 
$('.jscolor').val();

But, I suggest you use an ID for you Color Pick Div.